# programmatically remove react-native-vector-icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to programmatically remove a react-native-vector-icon upon closing a menu.

For the same effect with the menu text I did this:

```
export const menuTextColor = (isOpen) => {
   return isOpen ? 'white' : 'transparent'
}
```

then in the styles:

```
color: menuTextColor(props.isOpen)
```

I need to do something similar with a react-native-vector-icon. Doing the same thing didn't seem to work. How do I do it?

Code with the icon:

```
let Menu = (props) => (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <OffCanvas3D
      active={props.isOpen}
      onMenuPress={props.togglePageMenu}
      backgroundColor={'#222222'}
      menuTextStyles={{ color: menuTextColor(props.isOpen), backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
      handleBackPress={true}
      menuItems={[
        {
          title: 'Search Products',
          icon: <Icon name="bell" size={35} color={menuTextColor(props.isOpen)} style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}  />,
          renderScene: <SearchPage />
        },
        {
          title: 'Add Products',
          icon: <Icon name="bell" size={35} color={menuTextColor(props.isOpen)} style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}  />,
          renderScene: <AddPage />
        }
      ]} />
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Icon** from `react-native-vector-icon` allow to set props `color` directly so this should work.

> <Icon name="icon-name" color={menuTextColor(props.isOpen)} />

And I think you set both the `color` props and `color` style, that why the `color` style has been overrode.

Comment: Thanks however for some reason when I do that it is just always transparent.